# django file field not saving file to s3 bucket folder when updating

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, boto3

I am uploading file to s3 bucket in the below path:

bucket/folder/{custom_id}/file

I have the below method which I am calling in Model. In DRF Post method, the file is getting saved correctly to s3 and I am able to retrieve the path in GET. But when I try to upload new files in PUT method, the filename is getting saved in db, but the file is not saving in s3 bucket.

## custom upload path

```
    def upload_path_handler(instance, filename):
        return f'{FILES_FOLDER}/{id}/{filename}'

In Models.py

cc_file = models.FileField(
    db_column='CCFilename', blank=True, null=True, upload_to=upload_path_handler
```

)

This method is working in POST API call of DRF. How do I save new file to s3 if the file is getting changed on update of the field.

Comment: when you say the new file name is getting saved in the db.. is it the full url or just the file name?

Answer (score 0):

***What you can try..***

***1. Make sure you have the right S3 Permissions and Policy in place. Access 'Policy' via permissions tab in AWS S3 console for your specific bucket.***

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>/images/"
        }
    ]
}
```

***2. Install WhiteNoiseMiddleware & django-storages in your project environment.***

```
pip install whitenoise
pip install django-storages
```

***3. Add the following to `MIDDLEWARE=` in `settings.py`***

```
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```

***4. Following additions in `settings.py` are required to handle URLs from S3 correctly. The handling is done by django middleware & django-storages automatically***

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_KEY']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_ACC_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

***5. For aiming uploads into a precise S3 Bucket folder. (Additional)***

In setting.py set media root:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
```

In models.py use `ImageFiled` and add `upload_to=` takes in a folder name and creates it with the first upload!:

```
image_variable = models.ImageField(null=True, default="{default_filename)", upload_to='uploads/')
```

Reference: [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) , [whiteNoiseMiddelware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/), [S3 Access Troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-file-folder/)